# How can I run update-grub on a chroot filesystem

Tags: command-line, grub2, chroot

I've been building a live Ubuntu server (10.04 LTS) to run off a thumb drive and it's nearly there.

However, I've gotten stuck at one step.

I need to run `update-grub` but it's complaining about:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
```

My `fstab` file contains:

```
# filesystem   mount point     type    options                 dump    pass
UUID=76d2077e-9726-4f95-abab-323cb426b099       /               ext2    defaults                0       0
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
sys             /sys            sysfs   defaults                0       0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

oops... my bad.  It's as simple as mounting dev.

Strangely enough I tried this at about 1am last night and that didn't work.
This morning it did, so I'm not sure what was different.

To get a full environment just

```
sudo chroot /media/flash-drive
mount proc
mount sys
mount dev
```

And in case you have a separate boot partition

```
mount boot
```

After doing that I was able to see my devices in /dev

And update-grub actually works.  Now to figure out why it's not booting... that's another problem.

Comment: In 12.04, I had to mount `udev` rather than `dev`.

Comment: I was misled by Randall's comment as to mount udev rather than dev, but it turns out that it is still `dev` (of type `udev`) that needs to be mounted, as of today for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.